# Styling promoted links web part

Tags: promoted-links

I have a promoted links web part with 12 items. I would like to show the tiles in a 4x3 grid for which I'm using code.

Though I'm able to make changes to the UI, the tiles appear very close to each other. I would like to know if there any option to increase the space / padding between each tile?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the width of `tile-root`, `tile-content`

```
<style>
div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
width: 185px !important;
}

div.ms-tileview-tile-content
{
   width: 180px !important;
}
</style>
```

This will keep a **5px** border around the tile, if its width **185px**

---

> **Note**: the CSS style working only with the custom promoted list, not to the default prompted list like **`"Get Started with your Web Site"`** that created at a new site.
>
> [image]